# how to get sets list from flickr by user id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, flicker

I am using flicker jquery plugin and  i need to get users their sets list by their user Id.
I have search in flicker API but didnt fount any service for this task, but i know its is possible.

in the plugin I have this function :

```
 set: function( photoset_id, callback ) {
        return this._find({
            photoset_id: photoset_id,
            method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos'
        }, callback);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the API method you're looking for is flickr.photosets.getList found here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getList.html

If you're looking for other libraries to try out, the Temboo SDK includes this flickr method, and it's available for Android, iOS, Java, Node.js, PHP, Python, and Ruby.

Here's the link to this Flickr method at Temboo to test it out:
https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Flickr/PhotoSets/GetList/

(full disclosure: I work at Temboo)